# If $u \in H^1(U)$, then $Du=0$ a.e. on the set $\{u=0\}$

Tags: sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

> Provide details for the following alternative proof that if $u \in H^1(U)$, then $$Du = 0 \text{ a.e. } \, \text{ on the set } \{u=0\}. $$
>   Let $\phi$ be a smooth, bounded and nondecreasing function, such that $\phi'$ is bounded and $\phi(z)=z$ if $|z| \le 1$. Set $$u^\epsilon(x) := \epsilon \phi(u/\epsilon).$$ Show that $u^\epsilon \rightharpoonup 0$ weakly in $H^1(U)$ and therefore $$\int_U Du^\epsilon \cdot Du \, dx = \int_U \phi'(u/\epsilon) |Du|^2 \, dx \to 0.$$ Employ this observation to finish the proof.

PDE by Evans, 2nd edition: Chapter 5, Exercise 19

Here is my work so far. I tried what I can; are there any errors in this?

As $\epsilon \to 0$, 
\begin{align}
\|u^\epsilon\|_{H^1(U)} &:= \|u^\epsilon \|_{L^2(U)} + \|D u^\epsilon \|_{L^2(U)} \\
&= \left\|\epsilon \phi\left(\frac u{\epsilon} \right) \right\|_{L^2(U)}+\|\phi'\left(\frac u{\epsilon} \right) Du \|_{L^2(U)} \\
&\le \left\|C \epsilon \frac u{\epsilon} \right\|_{L^2(U)} + \left\|C \cdot Du \right\|_{L^2(U)} \\
&\le C(\left\| u \right\|_{L^2(U)} + \left\| Du \right\|_{L^2(U)}). 
\end{align}
Hence, $u^\epsilon \rightharpoonup 0$ weakly in $H^1(U)$. Therefore, at $u=0$,
$$\require{cancel} \int_U \left. \cancelto{1}{\phi'(0/\epsilon)} |Du|^2  \right\vert_{u=0}\, dx \to 0$$
 gives $\int_U \left. |Du|^2 \right\vert_{u=0} \, dx \to 0$. Hence, $\left. Du \right\vert_{u=0} =0$ a.e., or $Du=0$ a.e. on the set $\{u=0\}$.

Comment: Why are you assuming $|u|\leq 1$? If you change your equality in the third line for an inequality that calculation holds for general $u$ (use the Lipschitz condition). If $\int_U |Du| \to 0$ then $u$ is constant throughout $U$, which is clearly not true in general, but you do have that $\phi'(0/\varepsilon)=1$, which says...

Comment: We can use the Lipschitz continutiy condition ... it was given from the fact that $\phi$ is "smooth, bounded"?

Comment: From the fact that $\phi'$ is bounded.

Comment: That means $$\|\phi'(u/\epsilon) Du \|_{L^2(U)} \le C \|Du\|_{L^2(U)}$$ for some appropriate constant $C$? What about then for using $$\phi(u/\epsilon)=u/\epsilon$$ for $|u/\epsilon|\le 1$? I think we are also using that $\phi$ is bounded too.

Comment: Yes but also, since $\phi(0)=0$, that $$\varepsilon |\phi(u/\varepsilon)| \leq C|u|.$$

Comment: Does it have to be specifically $\phi(0)=0$? I was tempted to just have an arbitrary value of $u$ that is close to $0$ (i.e. $\phi(u/\epsilon)=u/\epsilon$). (Hence, my initial assumption of $|u| \le 1$, albeit without any good reason.)

Comment: Well $\phi(x)=x$ for $|x|\leq 1$. In particular $\phi(0)=0$.

Comment: @Jose27 I had incorporated your suggestion of $\phi'(0)=1$ into the last lines of my work, so that $\int_U \left.|Du|^2 \right\vert_{u=0}\, dx = 0$ (only when $u=0$), instead of having $\int_U |Du|^2 \, dx = 0$ for the entire region $U$.

Comment: @dragon When proving $u^{\epsilon} \to 0$ weakly in $H^1(U)$, why assume $u \to 0$? I think it is supposed to assume $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Can the downvote be explained please?

Comment: @Sherry Which line in my work assumes $u \to 0$? You're probably right, but I don't see it; I only see that I did $u^\epsilon \rightharpoonup 0$.

Comment: @dragon Hi. I saw it in the first line, after "Here is my work so far. I tried what I can; are there any errors in this?", it is "as $u \to 0$" Maybe it is a typo?

Comment: Ohh ... yes, it was a typo! It is indeed "as $\epsilon \to 0$". Thanks, @Sherry.

Comment: @Jose27 Excuse me if I reply on an old question, but I don't understand a couple of things. First, since by definition $u^\varepsilon(x) = \varepsilon\phi(u/\varepsilon)$ and $\phi$ is bounded, couldn't we simply bound $||u^\varepsilon||_{L^2(U)}$ with a constant $C$? i.e. write $||u^\varepsilon||_{L^2(U)} \le C$?

Answer (score 3):

Shown $u^\epsilon\to 0$ weakly in $L^2$ is the easy part, I think you already proved it. (I looked at comments, it has a good hint)

The trick part is to show $\nabla u^\epsilon\to 0$ weakly in $L^2$ as well. Applying chain rule will lead you nowhere. You need following result in Functional analysis

---

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $S$ be a total subset of $X^*$, i.e., the span of $S$ is dense in $X^*$, $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $X$ and $x\in X$ is given. Then $x_n\to x$ weakly as $n\to\infty$ if and only if $({x_n})$ is bounded and 
$$
\left<{y^*,x_n}\right>\to\left<{y^*,x}\right>\text{ for all }y^*\in S.
$$

---

Hence, by definition we need to prove that 
$$ \int_U \partial_i u^\epsilon\,v\,dx\to  0\tag w$$
for all $v\in L^2(U)$, but now we only need to prove that 
$$ \int_U \partial_i u^\epsilon\,v\,dx\to  0\tag 1$$
for all $v\in C_c^\infty(U)$
and hence you can use IBP and have $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$ \int_U  u^\epsilon\,\partial_i v\,dx\to  0$$
which is true since $u^\epsilon\to 0$ weakly in $L^2$.

Comment: The definition of weak $L^2$ convergence is what $(w)$ says. If you don't know what is weak convergence means, I suggest you to read some functional analysis books.

Comment: I guess I will need to go read those books. I'm sorry if I just asked you dumb questions, I just always forget that PDE theory requires a background of functional analysis, in addition to backgrounds in measure theory, multivariable calculus, linear algebra ... (the list could go on). :) (For the record, I have taken requisite classes in everything else besides functional analysis.)

Comment: Well, the functional analysis is kind of the most important one. It looks to me we only need LDCT from measure theory. :)

Comment: Sorry, I misread the argument...

Comment: @wisher Could you explain why instead of all $v \in L^2(U)$, we only need to prove for all $v \in C_c^{\infty}(U)$ in $\int_U \partial_i u^{\epsilon}v dx \to 0$? Thanks!

Comment: @Sherry It is due to the result from Functional Analysis which I mentioned in my post.

Comment: @wisher Thanks! Can I ask you a question? dragon assumes $u \to 0$ when probing the weakly convergence of $u^{\epsilon} \to 0$. But I think it is supposed to be $\epsilon \to 0$?  Is that right?

Comment: @Sherry. I think so.